# Why Restore doesnt end?

Tags: postgresql, database-restore, postgresql-9.5, pg-restore

First I thought was too big restore, so instead of a single 2GB *(compress)* db backup  I split into several backup, one for schema. This schema `map` has 600 Mb. Next step would be split for tables.

This one have some spatial data from my country map, not sure if that is relavant.

As you can see almost 2h. The disk arent really in use anymore. When restore start, disk reach 100% several times. But last hour has been flat 0%

[image]

And as you can see here I can access the data in the all the restored tables. So looks like is already done.

[image]

**Is this normal?.
There is anything I can check to see what is doing the restore?**

Hardware Setup:

- Core i7 @ 3.4 GHz - 24 GB Ram
- DB on 250 gb SSD  Backup files in SATA disk

**EDIT**

```
SELECT application_name, query, * 
FROM pg_stat_activity
ORDER BY application_name, query;
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that seems perfectly normal.

Most likely you observe index or constraint creation. Look at the output of

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity;
```

to confirm that (it should contain `CREATE INDEX` or `ALTER TABLE`).

It is too late now, but increasing `maintenance_work_mem` will speed up index creation.

Comment: 1GB if you have enough memory on the machine.

Comment: Looks like you are right. https://i.stack.imgur.com/8n06g.png I start the restore with 8 jobs. Is already 12:42 am, Should I let it continue until tomorrow or restart with more `maintenance_work_mem`? Right now is `64 MB` :'(  .. I have 24GB and is using only 5GB right now

Comment: I would let it run to completion, that is probably faster.

Comment: How change `maintenance_work_mem`? I update in postgresql.conf and restart service but still say 64 MB

Comment: I got tired, stop it change to 512 MB finish in 15 min :D